# How many positive integers $ n$ with $1 \le n \le 2500$ are prime relative to $3$ and $5$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand this example from my study guide and am getting no where with it and need some help.

Example: How many positive integers $n$ with $1 \le n \le 2500$ are prime relative to $3$ and $5$?

The example come from the chapter on Venn Diagrams.

Let $U = \{n \in \Bbb Z_+ \mid 1 \le n \le 2500\}$.
We need to establish the number of positive integers in $U$ such that
$\gcd(3, n) = 1$ and $\gcd(5, n) = 1$.

In this case, it is easier to count the integers that are relative primes with $3$ and $5$.
Note that an integer is not a relative prime with $3$ if it is a multiple of $3$. Thus,
$$A = \{n \in U\mid \gcd(3, n) = 1\} = \{3n \in U\mid 1 \le n \le 1249\}.$$  Can someone explain how $249$ is obtained?
and 
$$B = \{n \in U\mid \gcd(5, n) = 1\} = \{5n \in U\mid 1 \le n \le 500\}.$$ Can someone explain how $500$ is obtained?

Thus, $A = \{n \in U\mid \gcd(3, n) = 1\}$ and $B = \{n \in U\mid \gcd(5, n) = 1\}$.

We want to find $|A \cap B| = |A \cup B| = |U| − |A \cup B|$.

We have 
$|A \cap B| = |\{15k \in U \mid 1 \le k \le 166\}| = 166$.

Thus,
$|A \cap B| 
= |U| − |A| − |B| + |A \cap B| 
= 2500 − 1249 − 500 + 166 = 917$

Thanks for any help.

Tony

Comment: The solution from the study guide is very complete; can you pin down the part(s) that you don’t understand?

Comment: These two parts, for a start: A = {n ∈ U| gcd(3, n) = 1} = {3n ∈ U|1 <= n <= 1249} Can someone explain how 1249 is obtained? and B = {n ∈ U| gcd(5, n) = 1} = {5n ∈ U|1 <= n <= 500}. Can someone explain how 500 is obtained?

Comment: Oops: I just read a little closer and realized that either you miscopied something, or there are several bad typos in the original. It may be that you’re having trouble because you’re looking at the erroneous version and not the correct version. Before we go any further, please check to see whether the proof in the study guide actually matches what you’ve written here.

Comment: There is a typo,$1249$ should be $2500/3=833$.

Comment: As $\phi(15)=8$, modular arithmetic implies that $8$ out of $15$ consecutive integers are relatively prime with $3$ and $5$. Thus the answer should be roughly $2500 \cdot \frac{8}{15}$ which is more than half of $2500$. The answer provided is wrong.

Comment: @N.S.: $2500/3\ne833$, and in any case the write-up has much worse problems. (It’s $\lfloor 2500/3\rfloor$ that’s equal to $833$.)

Comment: And there are 2 other typos: the sets A and B define the numbers which are NOT relatively prime to 3 and 5, rather than those which are, as the guide claims, with the additional mistake already mentioned that 1249 shouuld actually be 833. Thus 2500-833=1667 of the numbers are relatively prime to 3 and 2500-500 = 2000 are relatively prime to 5

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Of course, but what I mean is integral part ;)

Comment: @N.S.: I knew what you meant, but what you wrote is simply wrong; I always deducted a little credit when a student wrote ‘$=$’ between two things that are not equal.

Comment: @bluesh34: It’s clear that the first typo is the omission of *not* from *It is easier to count the integers that are not ...*. It’s not clear whether $A$ is supposed to be the set of integers that *are* relatively prime to $3$, in which case it should be $U\setminus A$ in the formula, or whether $A$ is supposed to be the set of integers that are *not* relatively prime to $3$, in which case the formula is right. The inclusion-exclusion formula is so badly mangled that I can’t work back from it tell which was intended.

Comment: @ Brian M.Scott: yes, it's a bit of a comedy of errors!

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all of the feedback, I really appreciate it. The example I wrote here is exactly as it is written in my study guide, and, unfortunately, the study guide has a lot of typos in it. I also contacted the course tutor regarding this example, so hopefully he can help to clarify the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the numbers between $1$ and $2490$ inclusive as $15\times k +l$, $k$ and $l$ integers, where $k$ goes from $0$ to $165$, and $l$ goes from $1$ to $15$.

$15\times k$ is divisible by both $3$ and $5$;  adding $l=3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, \text{or } 15$ will give a value that is divisible by $3 \text{ and/or } 5$.  So $8$ of the values of $l$ give numbers co-prime to 3 and 5.  So there are $8\times 166
\text{, or }1328$ numbers in this partial range coprime to 3 and 5

Adding $5$, for $2491, 2492, 2494, 2497 \text{ and }2498$, gives a total of $1333$ numbers that satisfy the given conditions.

Edited:  forgot $k=0$

Answer (score 1):

Basically, let A be the set of integers between 1 and 2500 inclusive which are multiples of 3 and B be the set of integers between 1 and 2500 inclusive which are multiples of 5. The cardinality of the set of integers which are divisible by 3 or 5 or both is $|A \cup B| = |A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$ (by the inclusion exclusion principle) and so the cardinality of the set of integers relatively prime to 3 and 5 (call it $|R|$, noting that $R = (A \cup B)'$) will be $|(A \cup B)'| = |U| - |A \cup B| = 2500-(|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|)$ where $|A \cap B| =$ the set of integers between 1 and 2500 inclusive divisible by 3 and 5 (i.e. divisible by 15) so $|A\cap B|$ = floor(2500/15) = $\lfloor \frac {2500}{15} \rfloor = 166$.
Thus $|R| = 2500-(833 + 500 - 166) = 2500-1167 = 1333$

Comment: Hi bluesh34, thank you for your answer. I will do some reading on the inclusion exclusion principle. My study guide does not say too much about this, but I do have another mathematics book. I'll see if that book has any information on this.

Comment: No probs: note I made a mistake myself which I've just corrected (floor(2500/15) = 166, not 133 as I said initially)

Comment: I suspect the 1249 in the study guide was an attempt to find the number of integers divisible by 2 (which is actually 1250)

Comment: Although the guide may not mention the ie principle explicitly, this is what the author/s use/s

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this using probablity theory.

The probability that a number is not divisible by $3$ is $1-\frac{1}{3}$ and likewise for $5$ the probability is $1-\frac{1}{5}$.  Since $3$ and $5$ are prime and thus coprime, these are independent events and the probability of not being divisible by both numbers is given by their product.  Thus, the amount of positive integers $n \leq 2500$ that are coprime to $3$ and $5$ is:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)2,500 = 1,333.\overline{33}$$

We round this number down to get our answer of $1,333$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but I have not done any work with probability theory yet, so this is beyond me.